# Hadoop: cannot set default FileSystem as HDFS in core-site.xml

Tags: hadoop, filesystems, hdfs

I am using Hadoop 1.0.3 in a Pseudo-Distributed mode. And my conf/core-site.xml is set as follows:

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.default.name</name>
        <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
    </property>
    <property>
    <name>mapred.child.tmp</name>
    <value>/home/administrator/hadoop/temp</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

So I believed that my default filesystem is set to HDFS.
However, when I run the following code:

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
```

I thought that fs should be a `DistributedFileSystem` instance. However, it turns out to be `LocalFileSystem` instance.

But, if I run the following code:

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("fs.default.name", "hdfs://localhost:9000");
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
```

Then I can get a `DistributedFileSystem` fs.

Isn't my default FileSystem set to HDFS in core-site.xml? If not, how should I set that?

Comment: How are you running / launching your job? Can you post more code?

Comment: @ChrisWhite Is this influenced by how I run my job? Shouldn't the default FileSystem be set to hdfs after my core-site.xml gets properly loaded?

Comment: Yes but if you're launching your app with `java myjar.jar ...` rather than `hadoop jar myjar.jar ...` then the core-site.xml may not be on the classpath, and hence won't be loaded. Try and output the value of `fs.default.name` in your code after you create the conf object.

Comment: @ChrisWhite I am running it in Eclipse with the Hadoop Eclipse-plugin.  So does it go wrong in the way you just mentioned?

Comment: Try dumping the value of `conf.get('fs.default.name')` to sysout and seeing

Comment: @ChrisWhite As I can imageine, it is "file:///" by default.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eclipse environment doesn't know where the conf directory under Hadoop install directory to find the core-default.xml and core-site.xml unless these files are added to the Eclipse classpath to load first.

Since these are not added in the eclipse classpath, the default core-site.xml will be loaded from the jar file hadoop-*-core.jar (For eg: hadoop-0.20.2-core.jar for version 0.20) which has the local system as default file system and hence you are seeing `LocalFileSystem` object instead of  `DistributedFileSystem`.

So, to add the `<HADOOP_INSTALL>/conf` directory to eclipse project classpath, goto the project properties(project -> properties) -> Java build path -> Libraries tab -> Add external class folder -> Select the conf directory from `<HADOOP_INSTALL>`

The above should add your `/core-site.xml' to your eclipse classpath and  all your settings should override the default ones.