# WordCount command can't find file location

Tags: hadoop

I run Wordcount in Eclipse and my text file exists in hdfs

Eclipse shows me this error:

Input path does not exist: file:/home/hduser/workspace/sample1user/hduser/test1

Comment: Does your file have a extension? Like `.txt` that does not look like it is showing the full filename

Comment: Probably you need to set `fs.default.name` manualy before running the job or add hadoop conf directory to eclipse project classpath, take a look at this question for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16711665/hadoop-cannot-set-default-filesystem-as-hdfs-in-core-site-xml

Answer (score 0):

> Input path does not exist: **file:**/home/hduser/workspace/sample1user/hduser/test1

Your error shows that the wordcount is searching for the file in local filesystem and not in hdfs. Try copying the input file in local file system.

Post the results for following commands in your question:

```
hdfs dfs -ls /home/hduser/workspace/sample1user/hduser/test1

hdfs dfs -ls /home/hduser/workspace/sample1user/hduser

ls -l /home/hduser/workspace/sample1user/hduser/test1

ls -l /home/hduser/workspace/sample1user/hduser
```

Answer (score 0):

I too ran into the similar issue..(I am a beginner too) I gave the full hdfs path via Arguments for the Wordcount program like below and it worked (I was running the Pseudo-Distributed mode)

> **hdfs://krishl@localhost:9000/user/Perumal/Input 
>  hdfs://krish@localhost:9000/user/Perumal/Output**

**hdfs://krish@localhost:9000** is my hdfs location and My hadoop daemons were running during the testing.

Note: This may not be the best practice but it helped me get started!!